# How to programatically change a user image field to match the user's latest completed goal?

Tags: media, 7

I created several goals with the [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) module. Every goal has an associated image.

My users have an image field 'Last goal' and I'd like to change it to the image associated with their latest completed goal. As this doesn't seem possible with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, I'd like to create a custom module. I found in the `Goals API` that I can use `hook_goals_completed_goal($goal_id, $uid)`, but I'm stuck there.

How can I grab the user's 'Last goal' field and change it to `goal_img`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer thanks to the Devel module and the [user_save API page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_save/7)! After investigating a random goal with `dpm(goals_load(GOAL_ID));`, I wrote the following code:

```
 function top_goals_completed_goal($goal_id, $uid) {
    $user = user_load($uid);
    $goal = goals_load($goal_id);
    $fid = $goal->goal_img['und'][0]['fid'];
    $img_title = $goal->goal_img['und'][0]['filename'];

    $edit = array();
    $edit['field_last_goal']['und']['0']['fid'] = $fid;

    user_save($user, $edit);
}
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing! BTW, are you aware [Goals](https://www.drupal.org/project/goals) has a new maintainer now?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens: You're welcome Pierre. Thanks for letting me know you're not the maintainer anymore. I assumed you were still on the project, since you've been editing my questions, voting and commenting on them all around. ;-) I asked quite a lot about Goals in the past, but frankly, I've now abandoned the module, because I couldn't find any features that I couldn't achieve by using Rules. Hopefully, some more pros of the Goals module will be highlighted on the project's page.

Comment: Hey @Jeroen , in your prior comment it says "* ... you're not the maintainer anymore ... *". Just so that you know: I **am** the new maintainer ...

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the goals module, but it looks interesting.

I realise that you have tackled this using user badges already, but it sounds like it might not be easiest to tackle this by adding the image to the **goal**.

As the project page mentions [user points](https://drupal.org/project/userpoints) and [user badges](https://drupal.org/project/user_badges), I would suggest that rather than adding the required image to a goal directly, you install the user badges module, create a 'badge' to match each of the goals you have setup, and attach the image to the **badge** instead. You could then use the goal completion action in rules to award the user badge to the user.

Comment: I've abandoned the idea of using the User Badges module. Instead, I've created a 'Last goal' image field for every user and now I'd like to write a custom module that changes this field to the goal's image field when that goal is completed. That seems to be the easiest way. Any ideas how I can do this?